# How do I build a .so file in f2py without errors?

Tags: fortran, f2py

I am trying to build an extension module for the following FORTRAN module:

```
module mod
  integer i
  integer :: x(4)
  real, dimension(2,3) :: a
  real, allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: b 
contains
  subroutine foo
    integer k
    print*, "i=",i
    print*, "x=[",x,"]"
    print*, "a=["
    print*, "[",a(1,1),",",a(1,2),",",a(1,3),"]"
    print*, "[",a(2,1),",",a(2,2),",",a(2,3),"]"
    print*, "]"
    print*, "Setting a(1,2)=a(1,2)+3"
    a(1,2) = a(1,2)+3
  end subroutine foo
end module mod
```

I ran the following in Windows Powershell:

```
f2py -c -m moddata moddata.f90
```

But I got the following output, with many errors:

```
call "C:\Anaconda2\Scripts\\..\python.exe" "C:\Anaconda2\Scripts\\f2py.py" -c -m moddata moddata.f90
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building extension "moddata" sources
f2py options: []
f2py:> c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7\moddatamodule.c
creating c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7
Reading fortran codes...
        Reading file 'moddata.f90' (format:free)
Post-processing...
        Block: moddata
                        Block: mod
                                Block: foo
Post-processing (stage 2)...
        Block: moddata
                Block: unknown_interface
                        Block: mod
                                Block: foo
Building modules...
        Building module "moddata"...
                Constructing F90 module support for "mod"...
                  Variables: i x b a
getarrdims:warning: assumed shape array, using 0 instead of ':'
getarrdims:warning: assumed shape array, using 0 instead of ':'
                        Constructing wrapper function "mod.foo"...
                          foo()
        Wrote C/API module "moddata" to file "c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7\moddatamodule.c"
        Fortran 90 wrappers are saved to "c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7\moddata-f2pywrappers2.f90"
  adding 'c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7\fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7' to include_dirs.
copying C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.c -> c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7
copying C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.h -> c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7
  adding 'c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7\moddata-f2pywrappers2.f90' to sources.
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_ext
Cannot build msvcr library: "msvcr90d.dll" not found
customize Mingw32CCompiler
customize Mingw32CCompiler using build_ext
customize GnuFCompiler
Could not locate executable g77
Could not locate executable f77
customize IntelVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifl
customize AbsoftFCompiler
Could not locate executable f90
customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
Found executable C:\cygwin64\bin\DF.exe
customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable efl
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Found executable C:\cygwin64\bin\gfortran.exe
customize Gnu95FCompiler
customize Gnu95FCompiler using build_ext
building 'moddata' extension
compiling C sources
C compiler: gcc -g -DDEBUG -DMS_WIN64 -O0 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes

creating c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\Release
creating c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\Release\users
creating c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\Release\users\brian
creating c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\Release\users\brian\appdata
creating c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\Release\users\brian\appdata\local
creating c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\Release\users\brian\appdata\local\temp
creating c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\Release\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l
creating c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\Release\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7
compile options: '-DNPY_MINGW_USE_CUSTOM_MSVCR -D__MSVCRT_VERSION__=0x1500 -Ic:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7 -IC:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Anaconda2\include -IC:\Anaconda2\PC -c'
gcc -g -DDEBUG -DMS_WIN64 -O0 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DNPY_MINGW_USE_CUSTOM_MSVCR -D__MSVCRT_VERSION__=0x1500 -Ic:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7 -IC:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Anaconda2\include -IC:\Anaconda2\PC -c c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7\moddatamodule.c -o c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\Release\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7\moddatamodule.o
In file included from C:\Anaconda2\include/Python.h:58:0,
                 from c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7\moddatamodule.c:17:
C:\Anaconda2\include/pyport.h:171:33: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'Py_uintptr_t'
 typedef unsigned PY_LONG_LONG   Py_uintptr_t;
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Anaconda2\include/Python.h:8:0,
                 from c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7\moddatamodule.c:17:
C:\Anaconda2\include/pyconfig.h:314:23: error: unknown type name '__int64'
 # define PY_LONG_LONG __int64
                       ^
C:\Anaconda2\include/pyport.h:172:9: note: in expansion of macro 'PY_LONG_LONG'
 typedef PY_LONG_LONG            Py_intptr_t;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Anaconda2\include/Python.h:58:0,
                 from c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7\moddatamodule.c:17:
C:\Anaconda2\include/pyport.h:895:2: error: #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
 #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
  ^~~~~
In file included from C:\Anaconda2\include/Python.h:86:0,
                 from c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7\moddatamodule.c:17:
C:\Anaconda2\include/intobject.h:46:35: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'PyInt_AsUnsignedLongLongMask'
 PyAPI_FUNC(unsigned PY_LONG_LONG) PyInt_AsUnsignedLongLongMask(PyObject *);
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Anaconda2\include/Python.h:88:0,
                 from c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7\moddatamodule.c:17:
C:\Anaconda2\include/longobject.h:50:1: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
 PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyLong_FromLongLong(PY_LONG_LONG);
 ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Anaconda2\include/Python.h:58:0,
                 from c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7\moddatamodule.c:17:
C:\Anaconda2\include/pyconfig.h:314:23: error: unknown type name '__int64'
 # define PY_LONG_LONG __int64
                       ^
C:\Anaconda2\include/pyport.h:802:34: note: in definition of macro 'PyAPI_FUNC'
 #       define PyAPI_FUNC(RTYPE) RTYPE
                                  ^~~~~
C:\Anaconda2\include/longobject.h:52:12: note: in expansion of macro 'PY_LONG_LONG'
 PyAPI_FUNC(PY_LONG_LONG) PyLong_AsLongLong(PyObject *);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Anaconda2\include/Python.h:88:0,
                 from c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7\moddatamodule.c:17:
C:\Anaconda2\include/longobject.h:53:35: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'PyLong_AsUnsignedLongLong'
 PyAPI_FUNC(unsigned PY_LONG_LONG) PyLong_AsUnsignedLongLong(PyObject *);
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Anaconda2\include/longobject.h:54:35: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'PyLong_AsUnsignedLongLongMask'
 PyAPI_FUNC(unsigned PY_LONG_LONG) PyLong_AsUnsignedLongLongMask(PyObject *);
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Anaconda2\include/Python.h:58:0,
                 from c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7\moddatamodule.c:17:
C:\Anaconda2\include/pyconfig.h:314:23: error: unknown type name '__int64'
 # define PY_LONG_LONG __int64
                       ^
C:\Anaconda2\include/pyport.h:802:34: note: in definition of macro 'PyAPI_FUNC'
 #       define PyAPI_FUNC(RTYPE) RTYPE
                                  ^~~~~
C:\Anaconda2\include/longobject.h:55:12: note: in expansion of macro 'PY_LONG_LONG'
 PyAPI_FUNC(PY_LONG_LONG) PyLong_AsLongLongAndOverflow(PyObject *, int *);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:4:0,
                 from C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18,
                 from C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7\fortranobject.h:13,
                 from c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7\moddatamodule.c:18:
C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_common.h:221:9: error: unknown type name 'Py_uintptr_t'
 typedef Py_uintptr_t npy_uintp;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Anaconda2\include/Python.h:8:0,
                 from c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7\moddatamodule.c:17:
C:\Anaconda2\include/pyconfig.h:314:23: error: unknown type name '__int64'
 # define PY_LONG_LONG __int64
                       ^
C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_common.h:311:9: note: in expansion of macro 'PY_LONG_LONG'
 typedef PY_LONG_LONG npy_longlong;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:4:0,
                 from C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18,
                 from C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7\fortranobject.h:13,
                 from c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7\moddatamodule.c:18:
C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_common.h:312:31: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'npy_ulonglong'
 typedef unsigned PY_LONG_LONG npy_ulonglong;
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:4:0,
                 from C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18,
                 from C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7\fortranobject.h:13,
                 from c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7\moddatamodule.c:18:
C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_common.h:614:17: error: unknown type name 'npy_ulonglong'
         typedef npy_ulonglong npy_uint64;
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1809:0,
                 from C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18,
                 from C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7\fortranobject.h:13,
                 from c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7\moddatamodule.c:18:
C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
  ^~~~~~~
error: Command "gcc -g -DDEBUG -DMS_WIN64 -O0 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DNPY_MINGW_USE_CUSTOM_MSVCR -D__MSVCRT_VERSION__=0x1500 -Ic:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7 -IC:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Anaconda2\include -IC:\Anaconda2\PC -c c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7\moddatamodule.c -o c:\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\Release\users\brian\appdata\local\temp\tmpokkt7l\src.win-amd64-2.7\moddatamodule.o" failed with exit status 1
```

My FORTRAN compiler is GNU Fortran (GCC) 6.4.0.
My C compiler is gcc (GCC) 6.4.0.
I am using Numpy V1.13.3.
I am using f2py V2.

Could you let me know how to resolve the errors?

Thank you!

Comment: I have no idea at the moment why your compilation fails, but I was able to successfully compile your code using both GFortran 7.3 and Intel ifort 18.0.2, and used your module and subroutine `foo()` successfully in Python, in both compiler cases.

Comment: I think the problem has to do with the C compiler. When I specify the C compiler as Microsoft Visual C++ (msvc), then I don't get the errors above. However, I get a new error: I cannot find VC\bin\amd64\vcvarsamd64.bat. Could you let me know if you're MSVC++ installation includes this file? If so, could you let me know what version of MSVC++ you have? Thanks for the help